# How can I convert a path of UI elements to string/text?

Tags: macos, applescript, mouse, ui

I am using the following to get the UI element path for the mouse pointer location.

```
use framework "Foundation"


property NSEvent : a reference to current application's NSEvent
property NSScreen : a reference to current application's NSScreen

-- # Get display size
set display to NSDeviceSize ¬
    of deviceDescription() ¬
    of item 1 ¬
    of NSScreen's screens() as record

delay 3

-- # Get mouse location (relative to the bottom-left of the screen)
set mouseLocation to {x, y} of (NSEvent's mouseLocation as record)

-- # Calculate mouse y-coordinate so it's relative to the top of the screen
set mouseLocation's item 2 to (display's height) - (mouseLocation's item 2)

tell application "System Events"
    click at the mouseLocation
end tell
```

the result this returns will be something like:

```
text area 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Untitled.scpt" of application process "Script Editor" of application "System Events"
```

I want to be able to operate on this as a text string for debug output from Keyboard Maestro, but have no idea how to convert this sort of chain/path of UI elements into a text string. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an old trick that forces an error in order to get a message string.  The main issue is that trying to do something like coerce the object reference directly removes the scripting terms, so you wind up with the raw chevron syntax.  If that isn’t what you want, you can let AppleScript generate its own coercion error text, for example:

```
# Get text of object reference
tell application "System Events"
   try
      UI element (click at the mouseLocation) -- force coercion error
      --> "button 2 of toolbar 1 of window \"Untitled 1.scpt\" of application process \"Script Editor\""
      
      -- also --
      # (click at the mouseLocation) as text
      --> "«class butT» 2 of «class tbar» 1 of window \"Untitled 1.scpt\" of «class pcap» \"Script Editor\" of application \"System Events\""
      
   on error errmess -- extract reference from error message (English)
      log errmess
      set here to (offset of "Can’t make " in errmess) + 11 -- note typographer's quote
      set there to -(offset of "\"" in (reverse of characters of errmess) as text) -- last quote of process name
      return text here thru there of errmess
   end try
end tell
```